# Getting NaN when console.log()

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a project/game in HTML/JavaScript with a console, and I'm putting in "ping" in it. 
But when I run this code I just get "NaN".

```
function ping(IP){
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        console.log("64 bytes from " + IP + ": icmp_seq=" + i + " ttl=64 time: " + new Date().getTime() - start);
    };
}
```

Comment: you should use parenthesis to wrap `(new Date().getTime() - start)`

Comment: Read about [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and [type conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals). Your problem can be solved with parentheses.

Comment: you can use `+` to join string and number, but you can not use `-`, so you should wrap parenthesis to your minus work

Answer (score 5):

The `-` is causing an implicit conversion of this string:

```
"64 bytes from " + IP + ": icmp_seq=" + i + " ttl=64 time: " + new Date().getTime()
```

to `NaN`. The `+` and `-` in your line are evaluated from left to right, so when you get to the `-`, you are evaluating `String - Number`. In JS, this causes the string to be converted to a number (or `NaN` if it cannot be converted), which is obviously not what you want. `NaN - anything` is still `NaN`.

By wrapping the `(new Date().getTime() - start)` in parentheses, the numerical operation is completed first, then you are adding together `String + Number`. This results in a conversion from number to string, so your `console.log` will work as you expect.

Comment: i dint get the *result is converted to string part*. just because its in paranthesis will it be evaluated to string?

Comment: No, but if you do not put it in parenthesis, then the "new Date().getTime()" will be concatenated to the string on it's left side first. And then the "somelongstring" - start will be evaluated, by first converting "somelongstring" to a Number, which is NaN. And NaN - start is NaN, which is logged.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use concatenation and math...

```
" ttl=64 time: " + new Date().getTime() - start);
```

So add the code in parenthesis as follows...

```
console.log("64 bytes from " + IP + ": icmp_seq=" + i + " ttl=64 time: " + (new Date().getTime() - start));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ping(IP){
   for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
       var start = new Date().getTime();
       var newTime = new Date().getTime() - start;
       console.log("64 bytes from " + IP + ": icmp_seq=" + i + " ttl=64 time: " + newTime);
   };
}
```